# Is there a way to make the compiler throw an error whenever I put a string instead of a nlohmann::json object?

Tags: c++, json, string

I have this situation where my method needs a nlohmann::json object as the argument.

```
class MyClass {
  public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();

    bool parse(const nlohmann::json& configuration);
};
```

My current approach to give the JSON, which is fine, is the next one:

```
std::string filePath = "../folder/folder/file.json"
std::ifstream file(filePath);
nlohmann::json configJSON = nlohmann::json::parse(file);

MyClass object;
object.parse(configJSON);
```

My problem is that the compiler accepts the next piece of code, but I want it to differentiate between `std::string` and `nlohmann::json`, to make sure that I am passing a JSON already parsed object and not a random string.

```
std::string filePath = "../folder/folder/file.json"

MyClass object;
object.parse(filePath);
```

Then inside the parse method I am getting a runtime error when I launch the program because of course I am trying to access a string in a way that is not possible.

**Is there a way to do it either in the code or with a compilation flag in the CMakeList.txt?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might add a deleted overload:

```
class MyClass {
  public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();

    bool parse(const nlohmann::json& configuration);
    bool parse(const std::string&) = delete;
    // bool parse(const char*) = delete; // Else you would have ambiguous call error message
};
```